# Why jerky animation?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Why it does not work smoothly? 
I tried using a small image (500px width), but it's also jerky animation

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.load(new URLRequest("http://cevek.ru/img0.gif"));
    // http://cevek.ru/img1.gif 500px width
    addChild(loader);

var img_x = 0;
stage.frameRate = 100;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
function onEnterFrame(event:Event){ 
    img_x++;
    loader.x = -1*img_x;
}
```

Other variant

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.load(new URLRequest("http://cevek.ru/img3.gif"));
    addChild(loader);

var img_x = 0;
stage.frameRate = 25;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
function onEnterFrame(event:Event){ 
    img_x+=4;
    loader.x = -1*img_x;
    if (img_x > 100)
   img_x = -500;
}
```

Comment: Why did you set the frame rate to 100?

Comment: No matter 30 or 100 FPS, it's always jerk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a picture that is *way* too large for the Flash Player to handle.  It's not 500 pixels, but 20000 pixels wide! If that has to be scaled down at runtime, too, it is really no surprise the animation is jerky...

You should scale down your picture in Photoshop (or any comparable program) and use the scaled-down version for your animation - all your problems will go away.

If you need the full picture width for a larger view, cut the picture into smaller parts ( I would suggest no more than 100 pixels width ), and set all the ones that are outside of the visible area to `visible=false;`

**EDIT**

Also, you might want to consider using an [event listener](http://drawlogic.com/2007/09/20/howto-using-loaders-in-as3/) to wait for the image to be fully loaded, before you start the animation.

**More EDIT**

Use a Tween, or better yet, use [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/).

Comment: BTW you should still set the frame rate no higher than 25 - you will get sufficiently smooth animations that way, no need to hog the CPU any more than required